# 'Malformed' Error on R package check with --as-cran. Package built with Rstudio

Tags: r, package, cran

A few months ago I launched the 'table1xls' package, built using Rstudio. Since then some revisions have naturally accumulated. I wanted to share the revisions on CRAN in time for the R 3.1.0 rollout.

The problem is, for a couple of months now the --as-cran check option is giving me this annoying error:

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ...Error: Line starting '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>C ...' is malformed!
```

Now, I have no HTML in my package, nor any files that compile into HTML format. My work desktop (where this error occurs) is behind a firewall that requires the --internet2 flag when launching R, but Rstudio seems generally unfazed by that.

I saw this question pop up here and there, including on Rstudio's support pages where it remains unanswered. Any insight will be gratefully accepted.

Btw, my package is available on GitHub, user name "AssafOron". I wonder whether users can install it directly via devtools::install_github.

Oh, forgot to add: I'm using Windows (it's still XP over here) and this error is on the 3.1.0 alpha. But the same error was present with 3.0.2 as well. My top 2 suspects are something with Rstudio, or the firewall.

Answer (score 4):

That looks very much like a proxy issue.

A simple fix:  upload the package to [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) where you can test against the released version of R as well as the development version.  If they do not flag anything ... then you know you;re good.

Else, go to a local Starbucks or public library and use different connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Just uploaded it... now they say wait half hour :)

Comment: All right! It checked nicely with only a couple of minor notes. Indeed, seems to be the firewall.